# What requirements must my executable meet to run under Windows 10 Recovery Console?

Tags: windows, console, executable, recovery

I built an exe file (if it matters Delphi 5, yes 32bit). Works fine in Windows 10 x64. I tried to run it under the same Windows 10 Recovery Console. I get "This version of [the exe file] is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running....".

I searched for any requirements for the executables that can be run (or allowed to run) under WinRE but could not find any information.
I speculated that the exe needs a manifest so I copied the one from wscript.exe and included it in my exe. Still no joy.

So the question: how to build an exe that can be run under WinRE. I do not want to include a tool (as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-a-custom-tool-to-the-windows-re-boot-options-menu?view=windows-11)). My purpose is to be able to run a custom executable that is located on the drive with the Windows installation. Just as I can run wscript.exe or regedt32.exe.

Comment: WinRE does not support WoW64, so you'll have to recompile as 64-bit.

Comment: Thank you! Building then running a 64bit executable worked fine. I was somewhat mislead by the fact that the bundled regedt32.exe worked which seems to be 32bit...